# Terraform: Blob linked service in Data Factory

Tags: terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

Can anyone help me on how to create azure blob linked service in data factory using terraform script? I can see there are linked services of keyvault, postgresql, sql server, mysql, datalake but not storage.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you've tried? If you can include any existing Terraform code and why that doesn't work for you (eg show any errors or explain why it doesn't do what you want) then this will help people help you.

Comment: I cannot find a linked service code for blob. I am stuck on this.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_blob.html#create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no built-in terraform block for creating azure blob linked service in data factory. As a workaround, you can create linked services by using one of these tools or SDKs: .NET API, [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services#create-linked-services), REST API, Azure Resource Manager Template, and Azure portal.

In this case, with terraform, you can use [local-exec Provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to invoke a local executable after a resource is created.

If you are interested in looking at terraform resource [azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2.html). You can link to
Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

> url - (Required) The endpoint for the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
>   service.